# How to append values in a JSON list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm having trouble appending the values of existing dictionaries. The goal is to open a json file, analyze the existing dictionaries, see if any of the services exist, and if the service does exist then append the new password.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import random

#a set of characters to chose from for the passwords

char = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()\{\}[]-_=+/?.>,<|`~'
services = []
passlength = 0
b = 0

#this function takes your input on what services you want in your list of dictionaries

def service_add():
    serviceques = input('what service is the password for? ')
    service = (serviceques)
    if service == 'done':
        starter()
    elif service == '':
        print('you must enter a service name')
        service_add()
    elif service == ' ':
        print('you must enter a service name')
        service_add()
    else:
        if service in services:
            print('service and key already exists')
        else:
            services.append(service)
            #print(services)
        service_add()

#function to tell how long you want your password to be

def starter():
    lengths = input('How long do you want the password to be? ')
    global length
    length = int(lengths)
    makingPairs()

#this function creates a password and puts the password in a dictionary with each 
#service in your list then appends the set of service and password to a json file

def makingPairs():  
    global b
    global services
    global length      
    a = 0
    jsondics= []
    for line in services:
        a = a + 1
    for x in range(a):
        password = ''     
        for c in range(length):
            password += random.choice(char)        
        jsonpairs = {
            'Service' : services[b],
            'Password' : password
        }
        jsondics.append(jsonpairs)
        b = b + 1
    j = json.dumps(jsondics)
    with open('passwords.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(j)
        f.close()
        check_jsonfile()

#this function is supposed to open passwords.json and check each dictionary to 
#see if the service already exists

def check_jsonfile():
    #whatline = 0
    JsonDictList = json.load(open('passwords.json'))
    print(JsonDictList)
    new_list = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v != 'pandora'} for d in JsonDictList]
    print(new_list)
    print('\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    service_add()
```

this is the original data from the json file

```
[{"Service": "spotify", "Password": "5QF50W,!UG"}, {"Service": "pandora", "Password": "E=b]|6]-HJ"}]
```

when I run the code and try to delete 'pandora' just as an example it gives me this

```
[{'Service': 'spotify', 'Password': 'bMXa2FY%Rh'}, {'Password': '$m--c<CY2x'}]
```

The problem is that instead of deleting the whole dictionary its only deleting the key called 'Pandora'.
I have tried to change the `new_list` variable but it is still only deleting either the key or value, not the whole thing.

Comment: Please provide a small sample of JSON data and a [mre].

Comment: Unclear what all that stuff is. What I meant was for you to [edit] your question and put in a sample of what might be in a `passwords.json` file **into it** (not down here in a comment). I also requested that you add a little bit more Python code that reads the file and will reproduce the deleted keys problem you're having.

Comment: I've made some edits, very sorry I don't usually ask questions on here. The contents that gets put in the *passwords.json* file are at the bottom. The fully working script with comments is also applied to try and explain what each function does, sorry for the bad question formatting

Comment: That's a big improvement, but you still need to add a sample `passwords.json` file — it should contain fake passwords, of course.

Comment: everything that is in the file is at the bottom, in the grayed out portion below the main code. *[{'Service': 'spotify', 'Password': 'bMXa2FY%Rh'}, *{'Password': '$m--c<CY2x'}]*

Comment: According to what's you wrote in your question, that's the result, not the **origina**l `passwords.json` file which is what is needed.

Comment: [{"Service": "spotify", "Password": "5QF50W,!UG"}, {"Service": "pandora", "Password": "E=b]|6]-HJ"}] this is the original

Comment: OK, I think that's everything finally. Unfortunately I can't spend any more time on this right now (some of the logic is a little difficult to follow), but will get back to it in the near future. Meanwhile, other folks may also start working on it now, too.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and i'll edit the question to reflect the material i missed again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you're asking how to remove an item from a list of dictionaries, based on the value of one of its keys. You have:

```
new_list = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v != 'pandora'} for d in JsonDictList]
```

And when you give it this input:

```
[{"Service": "spotify", "Password": "5QF50W,!UG"}, {"Service": "pandora", "Password": "E=b]|6]-HJ"}]
```

...it removes the key/value pair `"Service": "pandora"` when you really want it to remove the entire dictionary `{"Service": "pandora", "Password": "E=b]|6]-HJ"}`. Your question also mentions appending (i.e. adding something to the end of a collection) but I'm not clear what trouble you have there. So I'm just answering how to remove an element from the list of dictionaries.

### Removing dicts from a list which have Service 'pandora'

So first of all, we can do this:

```
new_list = [d for d in JsonDictList if d['Service'] != 'pandora']
```

That removes every element from the list when it has a key called 'Service' paired to a value 'pandora'. It also assumes that every element *does* have a key called 'Service' and will cause an exception if one of them doesn't. If some of them might not have a 'Service' key you could instead do:

```
new_list = [d for d in JsonDictList if d.get('Service') != 'pandora']
```

### Removing dicts from a list which have 'pandora' in *any* field

Your example would also remove a *password* that was equal to 'pandora'. I assume that's not intended. But if you *did* want to remove any dictionary that has 'pandora' as *any* of its values, you could do:

```
new_list = [d for d in JsonDictList if not any(v == 'pandora' for v in d.values())]
```

Comment: your first suggestion was exactly what I was looking for, the way it gets saved to the file i wont have to worry about anything else being equal to Pandora or anything like that. Thank you so much!